# Memory allocation of program without any allocation syscalls

Tags: c, linux, mmap, allocation, brk

I am currently working on a `C` program in `Debian`. This program at first allocates several gigabytes of memory. the problem is that after the startup of the program, still it is allocating memory. I checked and there is no `malloc` or `calloc` or etc. in the main loop of the program. I have checked the memory with the `RES` column in the `htop` command.
then I decided to check the memory syscalls of the program with `strace`. I attached `strace` after program startup using this command:

```
strace -c -f -e trace=memory -p $(pidof myprogram)
```

**Here is the result:**

```
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.000311           0     10392           mprotect
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.000311                 10392           total
```

So it is clear that there is no `brk` or `mmap` syscalls that can allocate memory.

**Here is the list of all syscals:**

```
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 33.00    1.446748        6156       235        67 futex
 32.41    1.420658        8456       168           poll
 17.35    0.760549          31     24459           nanosleep
 16.24    0.712000       44500        16           select
  1.00    0.044000        7333         6         2 restart_syscall
  0.00    0.000000           0        80        40 read
  0.00    0.000000           0        40           write
  0.00    0.000000           0       184           mprotect
  0.00    0.000000           0        33           rt_sigprocmask
  0.00    0.000000           0        21           sendto
  0.00    0.000000           0        47           sendmsg
  0.00    0.000000           0       138        44 recvmsg
  0.00    0.000000           0         7           gettid
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    4.383955                 25434       153 total
```

Do you have any idea why is memory allocated?

Comment: I don't know exactly what is happening, but know the stack also uses memory so even if you don't use the heap at all there might still need to be allocations

Comment: What other standard library functions do you use? Please provide a [mre]. For example, `printf()` and friends allocate memory for their output buffer.

Comment: thanks. The stack allocates memory and then releases it. but here the memory is allocated increasingly.

Comment: @thebusybee I didn't use any `printf()`. I will send a table of all syscalls.